# BUG Found with Java Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

We seem to have found a bug with java regular expression.

We are trying to match different month year patterns that appears twice in a line or simply two year patterns that appear in a line.

But java seems to confuse part of the year with space separator.  *I have shown this problem to my professor and we couldn't solve it*.

To be specific we want to match "1/2013 - Jan 2014", as well as "2013 - 2014". *What happens is that in 2013 we get 0 to match separator  between month and year even though 0 is not in the separator pattern*. So we end up getting the same result as 2/13 
Here is code

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    import org.w3c.dom.css.Counter;

    public class DatePattens {
        //private ArrayList<MatchedDateObject> arryLstOfDates = new ArrayList<MatchedDateObject>();
        private ArrayList<String> matchedString = new ArrayList<String>();
        private HashMap<String,Integer> map ;


        private String monthPattern = "((0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])|(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sept|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*)";  // 3 groups
        private String monthAndYearSeperator="\\s*(\\s*|,|;|~|--|-|.|\\/)\\s*";      // 1 group
        private String twoOrFourDigitYearPattern="(19[0-9]{2}|[2-9][0-9]{3}|[0-9]{2})\\s*";         // 1 group  
        private String presentPattern = "(Current|Present|Now|Currently|Presently|Till Date|Todate|Today)";
        private String twoDatesSeperator = "\\s*(\\s*|-|~|--|,|to|til|till|until)\\s*";    // 1 group
        private String twoOrFourDigitOrPresentYearPattern = presentPattern + "|" + twoOrFourDigitYearPattern;  // 2 groups
        private String secondIdenticalMonthPattern="(([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])|(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sept|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December))";  // 3 groups
        private String dateToDateCompletePatternOne=
        monthPattern + monthAndYearSeperator + twoOrFourDigitYearPattern + twoDatesSeperator +  
        "((" + secondIdenticalMonthPattern +
        monthAndYearSeperator +
        twoOrFourDigitYearPattern +")|" +
        presentPattern +")" 
    ;               
        private Pattern patternAry = null;
        private Matcher matcher = null;
        public DatePattens() {
            map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
            patternAry = Pattern.compile(dateToDateCompletePatternOne, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            matcher = patternAry.matcher("");   
        }
        //
        // extract the two dates to look for duration afterwards
        // 1. check if the a year pattern exists
        //    1.1 if not skip to else at the end and return false
        // 2. if yes get the rest of the line past year 1
        // 3. check for year 2 or CURRENT/Present/...

        public boolean matchTwoYearPattern(String inputLine){
            String fname="matchTwoYearPattern";
            Pattern firstYearPattern = Pattern
                    .compile(twoOrFourDigitYearPattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher matcher1 = firstYearPattern.matcher("");


            Pattern secondPattern = Pattern.compile(twoOrFourDigitOrPresentYearPattern,
                    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher matcher2 = secondPattern.matcher("");
            //long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            matcher1.reset(inputLine);
            if (matcher1.find()) {  // 1
                String remaingString = inputLine.substring(matcher1.end(),
                        inputLine.length());   // 2
                matcher2.reset(remaingString);
                if (matcher2.find()) {  // 3
                    return true;
                }

            }       
            return false;   // 1.1 and end 

        }
        public String matchAllDatePatterns(String line, int lineNum){
            String fname = "matchAllPatterns:: ";
             if (matchTwoYearPattern(line) == false) {  // check if two years (or year and CURRENT/today...) present, if not return false
                 return("false:" + line);
             }
             else {
             }
            String matched = "";
            int i = 0;
                matcher.reset(line);
                if (matcher.find()) {// here we are matching the pattern dateToDateCompletePatternOne
                 System.out.println(fname + "line: " +line);
                    System.out.println("group count "+matcher.groupCount());                
                    System.out.println("group1 " +matcher.group(1));
                    System.out.println("group2 " +matcher.group(2));
                    System.out.println("group3 " +matcher.group(3));
                    System.out.println("group4 " +matcher.group(4));//so for 2013 - Jan 2013 input
                    //here matcher.group(4) is matching to 0 which we dont have in the pattern
                    System.out.println("group5 " +matcher.group(5));
                    System.out.println("group6 " +matcher.group(6));
                    System.out.println("group7 " +matcher.group(7));
                    System.out.println("group8 " +matcher.group(8));
                    System.out.println("group9 " +matcher.group(9));
                    System.out.println("group10 " +matcher.group(10));
                    System.out.println("group11 " +matcher.group(11));
                    System.out.println("group12 " +matcher.group(12));
                    System.out.println("group13 " +matcher.group(13));
                    System.out.println("group14 " + matcher.group(14));        
            }

                return matched;

        }
        public static void main(String args[]){
            DatePattens dp= new DatePattens();
            String fileName = "Resume.txt";

            try {
                ReadFile file = new ReadFile(fileName);
                String[] aryLines = file.openFile();
                int i=0;
                 long startTime =System.currentTimeMillis();


                    for (String input : aryLines) {
                        String output = dp.matchAllDatePatterns(input, i);
                        i++;
                    }

                long endTime =System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("Time required for this operation :" + ((endTime-startTime)*0.001));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        }

    }
```

so here this program should match to two date patterns which is month year followed by month year
but when i give input like 2013 - Jan 2014 so this pattern matching 2 as month and 0 as
separator and 13 as a year so my question is why its matching 0 as separator because i have not 
included it my pattern. So is it a kind of bug in regular expression
please help me with that

Comment: Are you sure you're following [the first rule of programming](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html)? It's *possible* there's a bug in Java's regex that has so far escaped notice. It's ***dramatically more likely*** you're misunderstanding something.

Comment: yes you are right i misunderstand and sorry for that

Comment: @ user: No apologies necessary, it's just the nature of things. :-) We've all done it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's all about this line, isn't it?

```
private String monthAndYearSeperator="\\s*(\\s*|,|;|~|--|-|.|\\/)\\s*";
```

You've added the dot (.), which matches ANY character - so also the zero digit in "2013". Escape the dot to only match the dot itself!

```
private String monthAndYearSeperator="\\s*(\\s*|,|;|~|--|-|\\.|\\/)\\s*";
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply actually i am new to regular expression so didn't understand that . will consider a as any character

Answer (score 2):

```
private String monthAndYearSeperator="\\s*(\\s*|,|;|~|--|-|.|\\/)\\s*";
```

**Problem 1:** `.` matches any character rather than the literal character `'.'`. Escape it as `\\.`.

**Problem 2:** `\\s*` inside the parentheses allows the separator to be completely blank. It should be `\\s+` so at least one space is required.

Fixing the `.` will make it so `0` is not treated as a separator. But then `\\s*` ends up allowing an empty separator, so you need to fix that, too, to get the separator pattern to match properly.

```
private String twoDatesSeperator = "\\s*(\\s*|-|~|--|,|to|til|till|until)\\s*";
```

This has the same whitespace problem: the middle `\\s*` should be `\\s+`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply i really appreciate. Now i am able to understand what i am doing wrong

Comment: Problem 2 : The reason i have add \\s* in seperator is if someone gives the input like Oct2013 to Jan2014 then also it has to work